# uitableview inside multiple view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have to 'repeat' a uitableview into 2 or more view controllers. Like using a uitableviewcontroller with its methods inside view controllers using the methods/delegates/datasources from the uitablewviewcontroller. 
Example: I've a uitableviewcontroller wich displays a twitter feed with its own style, so I need this table in more than 1 view controller and maybe just changing the twitteruser in each view controller (just an example).

TRY: What I've done is to create (with storyboard) a uiviewcontroller and a uitablewviewcontroller, both with their own methods. And on uiviewcontroller viewdidload, try to add the uitablewviewcontroller.tableview as a subclass. and this works! But the result is an empty table. I tried to set the delegates/datasources but it ddnt work..

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Add Table as subview
    thetable *t = [[thetable alloc] init];

    [self.view addSubview:t.tableView];
    t.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 2000);
    t.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor]; 
}
```

This code works, but just displays an empty uitable inside the view controller..

*thetable is a uitableviewcontroller object (.h, .m, and storyboard view)
*Just set the backgroundcolor to check if there's anything on screen
*using ios6

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you  are implementing the table view delegate and datasource methods in `thetable`.Also try `[t.tableView reloadData]` after adding the tableView to the view controller's view.

Comment: Yes they're implemented, even if I start the app straight to the uitableviewcontroller it works, but when I start with the view controller adding the uitable as a subview it's empty. Also tried to reloaddata but nothing..

Comment: Try to instantiate the table view controller with UIStoryboard's  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: and see what happens...